# CSS Shorthand Efficiency

Tags: css, performance, linear-gradients

What is the difference in efficiency between `background-color: #BADA55;` and `background: #BADA55;`? I realize it's quite trivial, but is there a difference in how the browser extracts the values of each. Also, on a slightly related note, on [CSS3Please](http://css3please.com) I noticed that for linear-gradients they specified them using `background-image`. Is there any reason not to simply use `background`?

Comment: If I told you it's 1 micro-second, how would it matter?

Comment: I don't know, but the 15secs I spent reading this question, I'll never get back :(

Comment: @phD if you have a situation where you are rendering on a huge display device (wall to wall, or a stadium display) with millions of cells and each with their own css, it will be a big deal.

Comment: I dare say you spent more time typing this question than doing it one way versus the other will cost your users in the entire history of your web page.

Comment: @srini.venigalla Why? The value will be interpreted by the browser no matter what size of the display.

Comment: @PhD It's more curiosity of how the browser interprets CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec makes no mention of how browsers should implement parsing of properties, and in particular, shorthand properties. All there is to it is a [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html), and the grammar says nothing about its implementation. How a browser parses a shorthand declaration then, I suspect, is entirely implementation dependent and not easily answered (unless you have the source code, of course).

In fact, the main reason why we have numerous CSS hacks specifically catered to IE is because of how differently (and often poorly) it understands CSS.

> Is there any reason not to simply use `background`?

The answer lies in your previous sentence:

> Also, on a slightly related note, on [CSS3Please](http://css3please.com/) I noticed that for linear-gradients they specified them using `background-image`.

Indeed; CSS gradients are considered images for use with backgrounds, and are documented in the [Image Values module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images). The individual background property they apply to is `background-image`.

If you use the shorthand property to specify either only the color or only a gradient, [it will use the initial value for the rest of the values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/about.html#shorthand). If this difference in used styles matters, then the difference in performance becomes completely out of the question, because it's no longer a fair comparison.

In this example, the second `background` shorthand declaration will completely override the first one, leaving you with a solid color and no gradient as the initial value of `background-image` is `none`:

```css
background: radial-gradient(white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) /* transparent */;
background: /* none */ green;
```

The purpose of the shorthand notation is to specify values for multiple related properties in a single declaration, so in order for both the gradient and the color to apply, it should be rewritten as:

```css
background: radial-gradient(black, transparent) green;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're second example should be: `background: #BADA55;`, but either way is fine and should *not* be something you need to worry about.

If you are curious how browser parse CSS I can tell you: it depends (ever worked with IE?). For Chrome you can see the source [on GitHub](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) and the Firefox source can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Source_Code_%28Mercurial%29).